# Implementing Django and socket.io to work together

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) to build a realtime application using Django and Socket.io (node js). I am building this inside a vagrant box, and has configured the vagrant machine in my host file. Now since the tutorial is an old post, I got many errors. However after fixing some deprecated codes, this is what it looks like.

chat.js:

```
var server = require('http').createServer().listen(4000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
    'authorization': function(data, accept) {
        if (data.headers.cookie) {
            data.cookie = cookie_reader.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error', false);
    }
});
var cookie_reader = require('cookie');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var redis = require('redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();
sub.subscribe('chat');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
        socket.send(message);
    });
    socket.on('send_message', function (message) {
        values = querystring.stringify({
            comment: message,
            sessionid: socket.handshake.cookie['sessionid'],
        });

        var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 80,
            path: '/node_api',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': values.length
            }
        };

        //Send message to Django server
        var req = http.get(options, function(res){
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            //Print out error message
            res.on('data', function(message){
                if(message != 'Everything worked :)'){
                    console.log('Message: ' + message);
                }
            });
        });

        req.write(values);
        req.end();
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/socket.io.js" %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                console.log("connect");
            });
            ...
            ...
            ...
    </script>
```

But now when I load the page I am stuck with this error

> GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LA7JSiV net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When in the index.html I change this

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
```

to this

```
var socket = io();
```

I get this error

> GET http://vagrant-box.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LA7NH61 404 (NOT FOUND)

What am I doing wrong? Please help me solve this problem. Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to solve the exact same problem. Are you serving index.html from the django application?

Comment: @JesusGomez Yes. I am returning  the `index.html` from the view of the 'core' app inside the `home(requrest)` method. Although it won't matter if its inside the `project-name.view`.

Comment: did you have any luck implementind this? It would be great to see the complete solution with socket.io 1.0+

Answer (score 0):

First notice that you can't serve the socket.io js from django, socket.io has to serve it's own js files because it does some clever magic to determine the files it has to send.

Change

`<script src="{% static "js/socket.io.js" %}"></script>`

to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

(you will have to change these urls on production)

after that you must let socket.io know the exact schema, host and port to connect to the node.js server or you will get a 404 as socket will try to connect to the port your django server is listening at.

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
```